# Textblock's height changes when it's Collapsed or Visible

Tags: windows-phone-7, height, visibility

I'm trying to make a reader for Windows Phone 7, I need to know how many pixels a line would take vertically, so I get a new Textblock and put all the words in it, and get its height as the string's height, here is my code:

```
public double getActualHeight(String tmp)
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.FontWeight = currentFontWeight;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.Width = contentsv.ActualWidth;
        tb.Text = tmp;
        tb.UpdateLayout();
        return tb.ActualHeight;
    }
```

but it seems not to work.

I tried to put some text in a Textblock, and get its height. When it's Visible, the height works fine, but when it's Collapsed, the height gets very big (e.g. 2k or 3k).
I checked [this page](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/07/difference-between-hidden-and-collapse.html), and it says when something's collapsed, it doesn't take any space on the screen, so it's height is invalid? Even it's ActualHeight? How can I get a Textblock's height when it's collapsed? Or how can I get the height of some text with something users can not see?
Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you achieve this by adding the textblock in to a **grid row** and making the textblock `Height="Auto"` and `TextWrapping="Wrap"`

If you do so, it will automatically take the height it needs to display the entire text.